# Firebase config forbidden

Tags: android, firebase, sha1, crashlytics

I am configured my android project in `Firebase` with `SHA1` key. Now I changed the gmail ID for console. So I deleted the old configurations and use the new mail id to configure the same. My problem is I can't use the same package name and `SHA1` even after deleting. What went wrong here.

Comment: package names must be different whilst SHA-1 can be same.

Comment: Hi, I don't want my old one. so I deleted. but still I want to change package name?

Comment: Yes because it takes some days or even one month to completely delete the project from firebase.

Comment: Are you sure it takes some days / Months to completely delete?

Comment: Yes, it has happened with me too. I had to change package name whilst using same debug SHA-1(its machine specific and remains same for all projects)

Comment: Ok thanks for your time :)